# What is the best way to create like button with django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make social network(small number of users).I have model User and Message so far.I want to create Like and Dislike buttons for Users to like or dislike messages.I could add new model like this

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

other option would be to extend the User model.What is the best way to solve this?What are pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hava a like and dislike field on the Message model using PositiveIntegerField, and then each Message can have any number of likes or dislikes. Then you need to add a link to the HTML to modify the number of likes and dislikes on any given post.

Edit: Set default=0 on the PositiveIntegerField.

Comment: You mean that I need to add this modification to templates?